# Expectation of product of Normal CDFs w.r.t. a bivariate Normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation

I am trying to figure out if there is a closed form expression for the following expectation:

$\int\int \phi(\gamma_1)\phi(\gamma_2) \mathcal{N}(\gamma\big|\mu, \Sigma)d\gamma_1 d\gamma_2$

where $\gamma = \left[\gamma_1, \gamma_2\right]^T$ and $\phi(\cdot)$ is the standard normal CDF. I am interested in the general case with an arbitrary covariance matrix.

I know the following result holds:

$\int \phi(\gamma_1) \mathcal{N}(\gamma\big|\mu_1, \Sigma_{11})d\gamma_1 = \phi\left(\frac{\mu_1}{\sqrt{1+\Sigma_{11}}}\right)$

but is there a way to extend this to the 2 dimensional case?

I will appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: How can the simple integrals you know the value of, be negative?

Comment: @Did: Sorry, I forgot the phi(x) on the right hand side.

Comment: This is equivalent to asking the value of $P(X\leqslant x,Y\leqslant y)$ for some specific $(x,y)$ and gaussian vector $(X,Y)$. There is no general analytic expression for this.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your fast reply